# Is there a way to update a returned value from a JS function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a chat app using Firebase and RN. In my firebase code I have a function like this:

```js
//all values are declared before, db is from firebase config which i do not wish to share
import "firebase";
async function getPublic(dba = db) {
  const messages = onSnapshot(doc( /*collection name ->*/"public", dba), db => db.docs())
  return messages;
}
```

Is there a way to update the returned value or something similar to that?

Comment: Its possible, what values do you want to update? An example would be helpful

Comment: I need to update the messages variable because it is a chat app so i need it to update

Comment: You want to update the messages variable after the function has returned?

Comment: Could your question be rephrased to something like *"you want to be notified every time the firebase updates"*…?

Comment: SUPA, in its current form, your code doesn't make a lot of sense as `onSnapshot` attaches a realtime listener and returns its unsubscribe function meaning that `getPublic` is returning `Promise<() => void>` and not the array of documents you are expecting. Can you expand the code you have provided to include the entire component where you are calling this?

Comment: i dont really have a complete code, i started like today and i want to set up direbase

Comment: samthecodingman why does it return promise<() => void>? i looked it in the docs and they use it the same way except console.logging it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of naming your function `getPublic`, consider instead `usePublic`. Or even better, generalize it so you can use different paths.

But first, we need to look at the definition of [`onSnapshot()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#onsnapshot) (a `CollectionReference` extends from `Query`):

```js
export declare function onSnapshot<T>(query: Query<T>, observer: {
    next?: (snapshot: QuerySnapshot<T>) => void;
    error?: (error: FirestoreError) => void;
    complete?: () => void;
}): Unsubscribe;
```

As you can see here, the `messages` aren't returned from this function, but an `Unsubscribe` function is (a `() => void`). So to update a messages array, you'll need to use `useState` and because you are using realtime listeners, you should use `useEffect` to manage the listener lifecycle. You also should handle the intermediate states such as loading, errored and fetched data. This results in:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { getFirestore, collection, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";

function useMessageFeed(feed = "public", firestore = getFirestore()) { // use default firestore instance unless told otherwise
  // set up somewhere to store the data
  const [ messagesInfo, setMessagesInfo ] = useState(/* default messagesInfo: */ {
    status: "loading",
    messages: null,
    error: null
  });
  
  // attach and manage the listener
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot( // unsubscribe is a () => void
      collection(/* firestore instance: */ firestore, /* collection path: */ feed),
      {
        next: querySnapshot => setMessagesInfo({
          status: "loaded",
          messages: querySnapshot.docs(), // consider querySnapshot.docs().map(doc => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }))
          error: null
        }),
        error: err => setMessagesInfo({
          status: "error",
          messages: null,
          error: err
        })
      }
    );

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [firestore, feed]); // <-- if these change, destroy and recreate the listener
  
  return messagesInfo; // return the data to the caller
}
```

Elsewhere in your code, you would use it like this:

```
const SomeComponent = (props) => {
  const { status, messages, error: messagesError } = useMessageFeed("public");
  
  switch (status) {
    case "loading":
      return null; // hides component
    case "error":
      return (
        <div class="error">
          Failed to retrieve data: {messagesError.message}
        </div>
      );
  }

  // render messages
  return (
    /* ... */
  );
}
```

Comment: tysm for the answer